# Best way to allow for extended use of Wordpress functions inside single.php

Tags: theme-development, loop, single

I am building a more-or-less distinguishing layout which forces me have a header far above the content in the DOM. A structure as follows:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="wrapper">
    <header class="entry-header" style="background-image:url({url-to-post-thumbnail-of-current-post});">
        <h1 class="entry-title">{title-of-current-post}
            <span class="date">
                <time class="entry-date" datetime="{the-time-c}">{the-time}</time>
            </span>
        </h1>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->
    <section id="main">
        <div id="main-content">
        <?php
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
            endwhile;
        ?>

        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- section#main -->
    <?php require_once(trailingslashit(get_template_directory()) . "php/single-secondary.php"); ?>
</div>
<!-- div#wrapper -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

As you can see I need to get information of the current post in `header`, but it's outside the loop and I'm not sure how to get that information outside the loop. Maybe I can run an additional loop, but wouldn't that cause overhead? Or can I extend the loop in a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All templates are build within the global scope, so you can access `$wp_query`, `$post`, `get_queried_object()` and `get_queried_object_id()` anywhere inside the template.

As this is in the header, I will also use a conditional check like `is_single()` to specifically target the single page

Comment: D'oh! Silly me. Thought the loop was the part where `while` runs. I've got a lot to learn. `is_single`isn't necessary I think because all of this goes into `single.php`.

Comment: If it is inside the header, you will need to use the condition. Remember, the header runs on every page. This will give unexpected output on other pages:-)

Comment: Just reread your comment. The loop is the while part. The loop simply just output the result from the main query and sets up the `$post` global. But post data can be accessed anywhere inside the template :-)

Comment: I guess I am confusing the whole-scale `WP_query` with the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can either run the loop, break after the first iteration, and then reset with `rewind_posts()`, or grab the ID for the first post & pass it to the appropriate template tags.

Personally, I would opt for the latter:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : $post_id = $wp_query->posts[0]->ID ?>

     <header>
          <?php echo get_the_title( $post_id ) ?>
     </header>

<?php endif ?>
```